# Apache-Spark Combining Data from Two Files

Tags: apache-spark

I want to combine only specific data from two files and output a file with columns for these data and how many times they appeared in both data files for an ssn. Should I be doing something like

```
val data = spark.read.json("file")
val ssn = data.filter(line => line.contains("ssn")).count()
val tickets = data.filter(line => line.contains("tickets")).count()
```

Is there a way to join the data based off the ssn and then keep incrementing up the tickets if I see the same ssn in the output file?

Also ssn is in a json key value pair in both files but on each line, they are in their own little json message and when I tried to read the files, I got a "_corrupt_record" Should I just be reading it as a plain text?

Comment: do you have a minimal example input & desired output? It is not very clear what exactly you want to join. Have you checked if the `join` operator is what you need?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response:

23:59:59 , {"ab":"cd", "ef":"gh"}, {"number":"1009","value":1800,"ssn":"123-45-0000","ticket":1}

That is an example of a single line, and my output would be a file with 

SSN                  ticket      value
123-45-0000    1            1800

Basically if the SSN appears again on another line or file, it would add the ticket column it currently has and adds what it reads again and updates the output file, same with value column. Where the data would combine based off the unique SSN. I tried reading it in as a json but that got me corrupt record.

Comment: I then tried reading it as a text file and trying regex but I get NotSerializableException. Kind of stumped since I just want to parse only certain parts of the line. I did take a look at join but I was not sure how to create two tables from a regular file

Comment: Better now, but still not 100% clear. Can you edit your post (not comments) with this clarification, and also add a second tuple example with the same ssn to show us exactly how you want to join them?